# How to map an IGrouping<Key, ValueA> to a IGrouping<Key, ValueB>?

Tags: linq, f#, igrouping

Given a function `f:ValueA -> ValueB`, how could I map an IGrouping of type `IGrouping<Key, ValueA>` to `IGrouping<Key, ValueB>`?

**Problem instance:**

Say you have this type:

```
TaggedItem = { Tag:Tag ; Item:Item }
```

and this query:

```
query {
    for i in taggedItems
    groupBy i.Tag into g
    select g
}
```

This would give you a seq of type: `IGrouping<Tag, TaggedItem>`, but I really want a seq of type: `IGrouping<Tag, Item>`.
The mapping function is: `fun taggedItem -> taggedItem.Item`

**Solution**

The solution is to avoid the mapping of groupings and instead do the transformation while doing the group, using groupValBy, as pointed by the selected answer. The selected answer also shows how to do the mapping from one type of grouping to the other, if you insist.

```
query {
    for i in taggedItems
    groupValBy i.Tag i.Item into g
    select g
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the mapping in the original `GroupBy`?

Comment: That would work too, but I couldn't find an example.

Comment: Well we can't give you an example easily without having *any* clue what you're grouping. If you could provide more context, we could help more.

Comment: I provided an example in F# hopefully the LINQ going on is obvious.

Comment: is there some reason you can't just use the function in the `select`? Like `select (MapFunc g)` ?

Comment: @mydogisbox MapFunc would need to be of type `IGrouping<Key, ValueA> -> IGrouping<Key,ValueB>`, but I only have the function of type `ValueA -> ValueB`.

Comment: Ah, right.  How about just using `ToLookup`?  `ToLookup(x=>x.Key, x.Select(MapFunc))` or something of that sort.

Comment: @mydogisbox well, turns out it is possible to avoid the mapping of groupings; the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
let mapGrouping f (xs : IGrouping<_,_>) =
    let projection = xs |> Seq.map (fun x -> xs.Key, f x)
    (projection.GroupBy (fst, snd)).First()
```

From your code example, I think you want this:

```
query {
    for i in taggedItems do
    groupValBy i.Item i.Tag into g
    select g
    }
```

At https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx, we learn that `groupValBy` "selects a value for each element selected so far and groups the elements by the given key."

Comment: That's it. Doing a search for "groupBy" on that page, I was not getting to know "groupValBy".

Comment: mapGrouping was what I originally asked, but I like your suggestion better.

Comment: @LayGonzález I actually didn't know about `groupValBy` before I saw your question -- I found it by searching just for "group" on the page :-)